# Win10 Jump List Missing Pinned & Frequent Files

Tags: windows-10, start-menu, jumplist

The "File Explorer" object in my Win10 Start Menu no longer displays Pinned and Recent files and folders in its Jump List. I couldn't say what exactly caused the behaviour, but it's happened on multiple installs after a few days of regular use.

I've tried changing the object action to Quick Access and back to ThisPC, clearing the [CustomDestinations and AutomaticDestinations](https://superuser.com/questions/233829/how-to-restore-jump-list-for-windows-explorer-pinned-taskbar-icon), disabled and re-enabled every Shell Extension and a few other things.

Can anyone help? I'm reluctant to regenerate the User Profile or Repair Windows because it's recurred four times so far.

(Windows 10 Pro x64)